# Increase font-size globally for CJK fonts?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Asian characters (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) make for more compact elements butI would need the font-size to be slightly increased when my site is switched to Chinese. How do I increase font-size globally?

I guess I could attached a class to the body tag, like so:

```
<body class="cjk">
```

and suppose

```
.cjk {
    base-font-size: 36px
}
```

might do that job?

Comment: I would recommend reading this overview from MDN to get an idea of all the options you have, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-east-asian

Comment: @DanAfterFiveCoffees, I think you've had too much coffee.  Suggesting a candidate CSS recommendation with next to no browser support really isn't the best advice.

Comment: If you properly classify the content in question using the `lang` attribute (on the `html` element, if the whole document is in one of the languages in question, or on the container element, if only parts are, and the whole page is multi-language) – then you can simply use the attribute selector in combination with the descendant selector to target all elements that need to. (And combining that with relative font sizes instead of fixed ones in px, would probably make this even easier still.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the root size probably won't give you what you want as the rest of the tags use the variable for pixel margins etc.

I recommend customizing the build and there are two options for fine tuning the elements:

1) using a body/wrapper class:

LESS

```
.cjk{
   & h1,  
   & h2,
   & h3{
      font-family:@font-family-zh  
   }
   ...
 }
```

2) use guarded mixins to change specific elements such as:

in *variables.less* to change everything together

```
.SetFontSize() when (@cjk) {
    @font-size-base: 17px;
}
.SetFontSize() when (@cjk = false) {
    @font-size-base: 15px;
}
.SetFontSize();
```

or in specific files like *scaffolding.less* for finer control

```
body {
  font-family: @font-family-base;
  & when (@cjk) {
     font-size: @font-size-base-adjusted;
  }
  & when (@cjk = false) {
     font-size: @font-size-base;
  }
  font-weight: @font-weight-base;
  line-height: @line-height-computed;
  color: @text-color;
  background-color: @body-bg;
  position: relative;
}
```

Bootstrap.less

```
@cjk = false;
... 
rest of the imports
```

Bootstrap-zh.less

```
@cjk = true;
... 
rest of the imports
```

option 1 is more verbose but you only have one file.

option 2 is streamlined but you have to switch out the files bootstrap.css <> bootstrap-cjk.css

Comment: Thanks for proposing those solutions - I like the idea of more fine-grained control, though I haven't worked with less before. So I guess I will need to create some separate files and re-compile the bootstrap.css to create a custom bootstrap-cjk.css?